# Android - Keep current text view data when going back to activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activities, the first activity has a `textView` which keeps track of a count (with a max threshold) based on when a user clicks a button. Now, when I go to my second activity to change the max threshold and go back to the first activity, I want the threshold to be the previous one (ie not the new one set, only when the user clicks a 'reset' button will the new threshold take effect).

For example, on the first activity, the threshold is 5. I go to the second activity and to change threshold to 10 then press the up button to go back to the first activity. The threshold should still be 5 until I click the 'reset' btn.

I know I can use `SharedPreferences` but based on what I read it shouldn't be used. I've also tried `onSavedInstanceState` but to no avail.

Comment: mind to share code some?

Comment: yes please share

Comment: what do you want can't able to understand your question are u use `AutocompleteEditText` in first activity and in second one also having `AutoCompleleEditText` ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use intent to pass values between your activies.

When you want to send value from one activity to another

```
Intent i = new Intent(thisActivity.this,  newActivity.class);
i.putStringExtra("your_key", value);
startActivity(i);
```

In your new activity

```
String value =  getIntent().getStringExtra("your_key");
```